# Why is Robotium slower when perfoming simple UI tasks in comparison with Android native code?

Tags: android, unit-testing, robotium

I'm using [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) to do some simple UI tasks on my unit testing project. I noticed Solo being significantly slower, I dont know why. I'm new to it.

This code is done with Robotium:

```
    solo.clearEditText(editTextLogin);
    solo.clearEditText(editTextSenha);
    solo.enterText(editTextLogin, "tecnico@mail.com");
    solo.enterText(editTextSenha, "12345");
    solo.clickOnButton(0);
```

This is done with native code:

```
m_Activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            editTextLogin.setText("tecnico@mail.com");
            editTextSenha.setText("12345");
            loginButton.performClick();
        }
    });
```

The code performed with Robotium is much slower when compared to the second one. I can figure easily that Robotium is actually mechanically doing all the stuff, while the native code is just setting values to objects, which can explain the difference, but my question best explained would be, when to use Robotium, the way it should be, the way the real performance gain can be achieved.

My apologize for any mistakes.

Comment: your java-code is not native code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It calls my attention you are so worried about test performance.

Android UI testing methods are quite complicated and leaves you with a test case that's hard to follow. Robotium is not focused on performance, it's focus in making an API accesible by developers to make their tests easier to write and read.

I wouldn't try to determine what's the most performant way to do a test. I would do it in Robotium, since it's easier to code and afterwards porting to native if necessary.

In my personal case I don't care Robotium making my tests slower. If that's the price I have to pay to avoid using the native UI testing tool, I am cool with that.

If the test takes too much time you can always run in your CI.

Comment: As for now, my testings aren't taking that much time, but it's a concern I have on a long a run. That's because I'm still into the babysteps of Android testing, and so I'm researching the frameworks available that could best suit our needs, in a convenience/performance rating. My first impressions were that one of the proposals of Robotium was to make it faster, so I guess I missed something. In fact, Robotium suits my needs perfectly when doing some types of tests, leaving behind some obscurities of the UI testing API. Thanks for your input, I will mark you answer as correct.

Comment: @Marcase. Not a good suggestion to run it only in CI. Test failure should be detected as earlier in the development cycle as possible. it should be run before merging the code.

Answer (score 3):

You should download the source code for robotium and debug through it. You'll see that there's a lot more going on under the hood. For example, here is a little snippet for clickonbutton:

```
public <T extends TextView> void clickOn(Class<T> viewClass, String nameRegex) {
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(nameRegex);
    waiter.waitForText(nameRegex, 0, TIMEOUT, true, true);
    ArrayList<T> views = viewFetcher.getCurrentViews(viewClass);
    views = RobotiumUtils.removeInvisibleViews(views);
    T viewToClick = null;
    for(T view : views){
        if(pattern.matcher(view.getText().toString()).matches()){
            viewToClick = view;
            if(viewToClick.isShown())
                break;
        }
    }
    if (viewToClick != null) {
        clickOnScreen(viewToClick);
    } else if (scroller.scroll(Scroller.DOWN)){
        clickOn(viewClass, nameRegex);
    }else {
        for (T view : views) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, nameRegex + " not found. Have found: " + view.getText());
        }
        Assert.assertTrue(viewClass.getSimpleName() + " with the text: " + nameRegex + " is not found!", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the remarking pyoussef! Indeed, Robotion is doing much more under the hood. I had downloaded the source code once.

Answer (score 0):

Try with different method as my experience of using
`solo.clickOnButton("String")` and `solo.clickOnButton(index)` also differ greatly.
as the first one seems to doing a lot of searching.